# Revert changes done by hot code swapping

Tags: java, transformation

I am performing hot code swapping using instrumentation and java assist and say that for a method `foo` with the definition :

```
int foo(){
  System.out.println("In foo");
  return 0;
}
```

I am setting the body to :

```
   method.setBody("return -1;");
```

Now after I am doing so, I perform some actions in my plugin with the changed code and then once my actions are performed (my actions don't change code anymore than the basic transformation I perform in the pre main step), I want to revert back to the code before transformation.

Is there a way I can achieve this?